# Importing data from Postgres to Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2012

I'm being demanded to develop a new software that must be built over SharePoint and use Microsft SQL Server 2012.

I have a DB in Postgres, and some of its tables will be used in this new project, so I must import these tables, everyday. I'd like to use WebService to do it, but they want it to be done DB-to-DB directly.

Postgres-to-Postgres is already done and it "works", but importing to Microsoft is being troublesome.

Does anybody know some MSSQL tool that can connect to Postgres and do the import?

Comment: The best (fastest) way is to export the data to a flat file (aka "CSV") and use bcp to import that data into SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically for this sort of situation (assuming that it'll be a process that's repeated on a regular basis) you'd use SSIS (comes with most versions of MS SQL Server).  Have a look at the first several hits on [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssis+postgres+source), especially the first one.

Another option is to connect to the Postgres database directly from your application via ODBC, and eliminate the redundant copy of the data - and get real-time updates instead of having to wait for the next execution of the SSIS job.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take a look on SSIS. I tried ODBC, but MSSQL keeps saying it no driver was provided (?). We are trying with ADO now.

Comment: How are you using ADO to connect to a data source without ODBC?